# Syntax React-select with formik

Tags: reactjs, react-select, formik

Hi everyone I should insert a react-select with formik. 
I'm newbie you can tell me an example? I use Formik "^2.1.2" version, and "react-select": "^3.0.8" version.
My error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined.
Thanks a lot.

```
<AsyncSelect
 name="myfield"
 cacheOptions
 defaultOptions
 loadOptions={fetchData}
 onChange={selectedOption => {
   formik.handleChange("myfield")(selectedOption);
 }}
 placeholder="search my field"
 value={formik.values.myfield}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using formik, you should use `formik.setFieldValue('myfield', selectedOption.value)` in the callback handler instead of `handleChange`.